# RestTemplate for Android is not properly converting json to http request for postForObjects method

Tags: android, json, spring, gson, resttemplate

I am trying to post a json object to a .net web service:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
answer[] answers = restTemplate.postForObject(url, new Gson().toJson(request), answer[].class);
```

The generated json looks fine so far:

```
{"request":1234}
```

but when sent to the web service with the help of the restTemplate the content of the http request is kind of messed up:

```
"{\"request\":1234}"
```

and the service responds with error code 400 bad request

**Edit: found the problem**

The problem was that I encoded the object twice.
RestTemplate already encodes the object to json.

the working code is:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
answer[] answers = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, answer[].class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to encode the object with gson as RestTemplate already does that

**correct code:**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
answer[] answers = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, answer[].class);
```